# iTerm2 captured output with watch script

Tags: iterm, zsh

iTerm's [Captured Output](https://iterm2.com/documentation-captured-output.html) is a great feature: I can run a build and open any files with problems, focused on the troublesome line in whatever editor I choose.

The one problem I've had with it is running a `watch` script that rebuilds my application when files change. In this case, when I click captured output, it sends my trigger command to a terminal prompt that is already busy running another process. Does anyone have any clever ideas to make this work?